# Grails can't make HTTP request to PHP script on same server?

Tags: php, grails

I need my Grails app at http://myserver.com/app/ to hit a PHP script on the same server. I'm using groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder to make the request, which works if the script is on another server. But if I move the script to http://myserver.com/php/script.php, I get

```
java.net.ConnectException
Message
Connection refused
```

The script is working normally in a web browser at http://myserver.com/php/script.php

How can I get Grails to make the request?

Comment: It sounds like it could have to do with how the apache server is set up. Can you from the command line of that box do a CURL and get the call to work?

Comment: Yep - that's it. Connection refused from the terminal too. Same PHP script works fine from outside.

Comment: Its probably in the set up with apache since you have two services set up working I wonder if there isn't something happening with a load balancer or something else in front of this box.

Comment: It turns out the server did not want to connect to itself using the outside URL. http://localhost is working to hit the PHP script from tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server refused an HTTP request from & to itself using the public URL. The request works as intended if made using the server name 'localhost'.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that Grails runs on a Java EE (typically Tomcat) web server, and the PHP file you're moving is probably running on an Apache/Apache2 Web Server? (Tomcat is also made by Apache, so this name is unfortunate.)

You can't just move a PHP file from one server to another and expect it to work. You would have to set up the straight C Apache on the server where Grails is running, probably configure it to run on a different port (since if both Tomcat and Apache are listening for 80, they would conflict), install the PHP module, and set up your PHP application.

Comment: I wish that were the problem. Both tomcat and PHP are running on my server. I can hit the PHP script on myserver from my app running locally and my HTTP request works from the grails app on my server if I hit the PHP running somewhere else.

Comment: So you have both webservers set up...are you trying to connect with http://localhost:80/php/myscript.php? It may help to post the code you're using to make the HTTP request.

Comment: My colleague set up the apache/php server so that myfolder/ maps to my tomcat app. Everything else about my deployed grails app works normally - evening making this same HTTP request to the old server. I'm using the full public URL for the server eg. http://www.myserver.com/script.php which works fine if I'm running the grails app locally with 'grails run-app'.

Comment: So is the full public URL mapped to Tomcat, Apache, or both? If they're running on different ports, and you're using that URL, you may be doing the equivalent of asking your Grails application to connect to itself, unless you're explicitly sure that your DNS is resolving correctly. If you know that you're guaranteed to be running on the same box, you should probably just use localhost:port in the URL.

Comment: From a web browser, http://myserver.com/script.php is a working PHP script and http://myserver.com/app/ is a working tomcat/grails app. The only thing that fails is that the grails app, when deployed there, tries to request the php script in that location. Move either to a different server and the request works.